# What tools should I deploy to support AWS for a Managed Services company?

Tags: amazon-web-services, toolchain

I work for a managed services company and am working out a plan to retrofit our customer support machines to support AWS in a general way.

We use Ansible and lots of ssh port forwarding to connect to traditional, non-cloud, boxes (Windows, Linux, AIX, Firewalls, routers, UC, other Cisco stuff).

Beyond the AWS CLI, what tools should I deploy to my Linux and Windows support boxes for managing, monitoring and troubleshooting AWS that are different than the traditional tools?

Comment: What kind of AWS resources/services ? What do you really mean by managing/montioring/troubleshooting AWS ? AWS by itself is very vague.

Comment: @tensibai that's pretty much what performing [managed services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_services) is.  The AWS resources are whatever our customers want out of AWS (probably enterprisey business stuff, not the esoteric stuff.  Everything from S3, SNS, SQS, EBS, Lambda, Glacier, Databases, Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a box is probably not the best solution, mostly because there's no real need for it.

You should ask for an access to AWS console in customer account with proper rights fitting your responsibilities and maybe setup [AWS config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/), [Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) for the monitoring and alerting part, [Cloudtrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) and maybe [Amazon Inspector](https://aws.amazon.com/inspector/) for the audit part.

To ensure machines and AWS services themselves are properly configured you may rely on AWS Config/Amazon Inspector or tools like [inspec](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/platforms/) (and here you may or may not need a bastion host on your customer VPC to check other machines, this mostly depends on the agreement you have with customer about direct links/VPN)